# TouchableNativeFeedback on a component does not execute the onPress function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have something like this:

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback
  onPress={this._changeAccount.bind(this, user)}
  delayPressIn={0}
  delayPressOut={0}
  useForeground={true}
  background={RippleColor('#ccc')}
>
  <PhotoStatus>
</TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

When I click on the "PhotoStatus" component, nothing happens.

The onPress function is not called.

It would be such a thing:
PhotoStatus

```
<View>
  <Image
    source={image}
    style={{
      width: dim - 30,
      height: dim - 30,
      borderRadius: (dim - 30) / 2,
    }}
  />
</View>
```

if instead I replace  directly with the component code contained in it, it works.

In the example on expo the used where in the image below there are the two red squares marked.

[image]

Link Expo: [expo](https://snack.expo.io/BkYzYAMwQ)

Comment: @PritishVaidya: Only on android, because I'm using DrawerLayoutAndroid which only works on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your component in View and it should fix the error

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback
  onPress={this._changeAccount.bind(this, user)}
  delayPressIn={0}
  delayPressOut={0}
  useForeground={true}
  background={RippleColor('#ccc')}
>
  <View>
   <PhotoStatus>
  </View>
</TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/ByTW41QvQ)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I do not explain why it happens.

Comment: most probably because of layout issue, Android is not as forgiving as IOS. Try inspect the element using react-devtools

Comment: I see.
Ot. What do you think of the module I'm trying to create?
Any suggestions? ;)

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to create but it looks good :-)

Comment: You know the draw layout that uses android, that.
A module that allows specifying parameters to make it happen.
example: google email, google playstore.

P.S.
if you have time you could take a look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019659/react-native-drawerlayoutandroid-drawerwidth-that-fits-the-content