# TouchableNativeFeedback onPress not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am currently facing a challenge [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059551/touchablenativefeedback-on-a-component-does-not-execute-the-onpress-function), however the solution is not working for me.

I have a modal on which I am creating a button to close the modal. This is a functional component which gets the function in modalClosed.

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={props.modalClosed}>
       <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#5d5d5d', padding: 10 }}>
             <Text style={[globalStyles.text, { textAlign: 'center' }]}>Close!</Text>
       </View>
</TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

For some reason this is not executing onPress event.

However if I replace this code with below it works.

```
<Button title="Close" onPress={props.modalClosed} color='#5d5d5d' />
```

A similar implementation using TouchableNativeFeedback works on another screen (non modal). Can someone please explain if there's something am doing wrong?

**Sample link**

https://snack.expo.io/HylsYzoIS

Comment: An expo link would give more insight.I have tried making one both the buttons are working for me.https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/so  Also if you are wrapping views inside touchables then try to change view's pointer events.https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#pointerevents

Comment: Thanks Karthik. That served as another pointer/workaround. Please check the update for the expo link. Its exactly same code except I am not exporting the control to another js.

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar issue and this was my solution.
Error - Do not import like so:
import { TouchableNativeFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

Solution: 
I imported TouchableNativeFeedback from 'react-native' like so:
import { TouchableNativeFeedback } from 'react-native';

I think TouchableOpacity and TouchableNativeFeedback do not fire onPress in a Modal component when imported from 'react-native-gesture-handler', only Button works.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you used state in your code, but I believe you can try to set state like below

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modalOpen: false
        };
    }

    closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({ modalOpen: false });
    }

    <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this.modalClosed} />
```

Or, did you try to use modal component? I doubt it works with TouchableNativeFeedback wrapper though

```
    <Modal 
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={true}
          visible={true}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }} >
```

hope it helps!!